# Objective C iOS positioning of code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

Im very new to Objective-C and am currently learning how to use Xcode and create iOS applications. I am currently testing a Navigation based application. As part of my display I need to download web data, strip the html tags, format the string etc, which takes quite alot of code. I found when this code is inserted into the implementation file its quite slow in the iPhone simulator.
This may seem like a really obvious question but am I  right putting the code in the View implementation file? or should I create a separate file to do all the data handling then pass the results to the view file? 
Once again, sorry if this is trivial and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Technically, what you are doing now is fine. However, a common strategy for effective coding is called Model-View-Controller, where you separate components that do different things. For your example, the downloading and processing should take place in the model section, which is where content comes from. The controller is simply responsible for taking the model's data and passing it to the view. The view is already provided as part of `UINavigationViewController`. Again, this doesn't affect performance, it's just a style that makes later maintenance easier.

## EDIT

In response to your second question, here's what you can do (assuming you have `MyModel` and `MyController`).

`MyModel.h`:

```
@interface MyModel : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_data;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;
@end
```

`MyModel.m`:

```
@implementation MyModel

@synthesize data = _data;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.data = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        // do your processing here and add it to self.data
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, in `MyController.m`, initialize an instance of `MyModel` and access `model.data` whenever you want that array.

Comment: Ah thanks very much for this, so if I wanted to create a model section I would simply go File > new file > Objective C Class > NSObject? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, model classes all inherit from `NSObject`. Then you create a new instance of your model in your controller and let it handle all the processing.

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, but when I create one of these NSobject files, it creates the implementation and interface file, which is all fine. So if I put my code in there, how would I go about sending them to the view controller files? For example I have to download some data, and after much tweaking, part of the data eventually becomes the text in the cells of my second table view controller. Sorry if this seems trivial again, appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do any data fetching in a view class. View classes manage displaying data only. Start with Apple's [Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) document, and follow the links to [The Model View Controller Design Pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

The summary is that you want a collection of Model classes that hold your data, independent of how it is displayed. You want View classes that display your data, independent of how it is gathered and calculated. And you want Controller classes that glue the two together.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob, this stuff is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hard question, I think you'd better write the code in some controller object rather than in your view object. A view would only worry about displaying the information, while the controller would retrieve the data and pass it to the view.
And as your tests suggest, try retrieving the data in a way that doesn't block your app while doing so.
In this case you should consider reading [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) from Apple documentation, which cover the subject.

Comment: Wanted to accept both you and Rob as my accepted answer as both are equally good, thanks very much for the help, will have a look at the docs now.

Comment: consider voting up both of us instead ;-)

Comment: Will do when I have enough rep!

Comment: Hi Vince, I had a look into threading and I think its the solution to my problems. Just a few questions: If i have two table view controllers, and the said code includes downloading a html website page and stripping html tags etc to get data. If I need said data at the second view controller, I presume it would be quicker to load the html data in the first view controller (so the program works on downloading the data as soon as it is launched rather than when the user enters the second view controller?). Do you have any suggestions to how I would go about this? Thanks very much.